# Can't save google profile image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-oauth

I'm working on authenticating with Google. I could fetch Google auth info at all but couldn't save profile picture. Carrierwave would work and I could find google image url also. But I couldn't save...

I've got this error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/carrierwave-2.0.0/lib/carrierwave/downloader/remote_file.rb:28:in `filename_from_header'
```

**apps/models/user.rb**

```
def self.find_for_google_oauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    binding.pry
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.username = auth.info.name
    user.remote_image_url = auth.info.image
    user.confirmed_at = Time.now.utc
  end
end
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2,
  Rails.application.credentials.google[:client_id],
  Rails.application.credentials.google[:client_secret],
  skip_jwt: true,
  scope: 'email profile',
  redirect_uri: "#{Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:host_domain]}/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback"
```

Answer (score 1):

I passed through after version down for carrierwave(1.3.1).